# Add menu as last item - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm using `wp_nav_menu_main_items` to add a flag link to the end of my main menu. This works well - however I also have Woocommerce running which also adds a cart to the end of the menu.

I'm trying to add the flag after the Woocommerce cart. However it currently appears before it. Is there any way to modify the below to always set the flag link as the last menu item instead of the Woocommerce Cart?

```
//Add Flag as the last menu item
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_main_items', 'add_flag_to_nav', 10, 2 );

function add_flag_to_nav( $items, $args )
{
    $flag = '<li class="flag"><a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '">' . __('.') . '</a></li>';
    $items = $items . $flag;
    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this by using the priority parameter in the function, i.e the 10 in the (10, 2). I changed the 10 to a higher number to make it run after the woocommerce menu addition function.

Comment: Yes exactly ... ^^

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a closer look on the add_filter function of WordPress? It has a priority argument:

```
//Add Flag as the last menu item
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_main_items', 'add_flag_to_nav', 100, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks, literally just worked this out myself. Cheers, Matt